# feature extractor implementing an SVM with scikit-learn in handwritten digit example

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

in guide talk about: " In the case of supervised problem, explanatory variables are stored in the .target member." What does it means?

in this example in scikit site:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html
I do not comprehend:

1) If uses any feature extractor (edge detection) for recognizing digits.

2) What mean numbers in target vector? it is the corresponding number that image show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `datasets.load_digits()` is an object of type `Bunch`, a convenience class for representing a labeled dataset. There is no feature extraction, the digits dataset just contains bitmaps. The numbers in the target vector are indeed the digits represented by the bitmaps, i.e. the labels/targets to be trained on/predicted.

Comment: if i wanna use this example with my own images and use an Hog feature extractor, i put Hog feature vector in data?        classifier.fit(data[:n_samples / 2], digits.target[:n_samples / 2])

Comment: Just put your hog features is a 2D array with shape `(n_samples, n_features)` and integer identifiers for the sign of each sample in a 1D array with shape `(n_samples,)` and then call: `classifier.fit(hog_features, sign_ids)`.